# ASP.NET Core Web API - HangFire Cron schedule failed to run

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, asp.net-web-api, hangfire

In ASP.NET Core-6 application, I am implementing Recurring Job using HangFire.

I have a 3rd party api (JSON) to be consumed and inserted into the database 2am daily.

API:

```
"https://api.thirdpartycompany.com:2233/api/BranchDetail"
```

In appsettings.json I have:

```
"Endpoints": {
  "branchUrl": "https://api.thirdpartycompany.com:2233/api/BranchDetail"
}
```

API:

```
{
    "Branches": [
        {
            "BranchName": "Accra",
            "BranchNumber": 1,
            "Country": "Ghana"
        },
        {
            "BranchName": "Kumasi",
            "BranchNumber": 2,
            "Country": "Ghana"
        },
        ...
}
```

The core is as shown below:

Entity:

```
public class Branch
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string BranchName { get; set; }
    public int BranchNumber { get; set; }
}
```

DTO:

```
public class BranchCreateUpdateDto
{
    public string BranchName { get; set; }
    public int BranchNumber { get; set; }
}

public class BranchResponse
{
    public List<BranchCreateUpdateDto> Branches
    {
        get;
        set;
    }
}
```

BaseResponse:

```
public class BaseResponse
{
    public bool Success { get; set; } = true;
    public string Message { get; set; }
}
```

Mapping:

```
public class AdminMapperProfile: Profile
{
    public AdminMapperProfile()
    {
        CreateMap<BranchCreateUpdateDto, Branch>().ReverseMap();
    }
}
```

Repository:

```
public class GenericRepository<T> : IGenericRepository<T> where T : class
{
    private readonly ApplicationDbContext _dbContext;
    private readonly DbSet<T> _dbSet;

    public GenericRepository(ApplicationDbContext dbContext)
    {
        _dbContext = dbContext;
        _dbSet = _dbContext.Set<T>();
    }
    public async Task InsertAsync(T entity)
    {
        await _dbSet.AddAsync(entity);
    }
    public T GetById(string id)
    {
        return _dbSet.Find(id);
    }
    public void Update(T entity)
    {
        _dbContext.Set<T>().Update(entity);
    }
}
```

Interface:

```
public interface IAdminBranchRepository : IGenericRepository<Branch>
{

}
```

Implementation:

```
public class AdminBranchRepository : GenericRepository<Branch>, IAdminBranchRepository
{
    private readonly ApplicationDbContext _dbContext;
    private readonly DbSet<Branch> _branches;

    public AdminBranchRepository(ApplicationDbContext dbContext) : base(dbContext)
    {
        _dbContext = dbContext;
        _branches = _dbContext.Set<Branch>();
    }
}
```

IUnitOfWork:

```
public interface IUnitOfWork : IDisposable
{
    IAdminBranchRepository Branches { get; }
    Task Save();
}
```

UnitOfWork:

```
public class UnitOfWork : IUnitOfWork
{
    private readonly ApplicationDbContext _dbContext;
    private IAdminBranchRepository _branches;

    public UnitOfWork(
        ApplicationDbContext dbContext,
        )
    {
        _dbContext = dbContext;
    }
    public IAdminBranchRepository Branches => _branches ??= new AdminBranchRepository(_dbContext);
    public async Task Save()
    {
        await _dbContext.SaveChangesAsync();
    }
}
```

Service:

Interface:

```
Task<BaseResponse> CreateBranchAsync();
```

Implementation:

```
public class AdminBranchService : IAdminBranchService
{
    private readonly ApplicationDbContext _dbContext;
    private readonly IMapper _mapper;
    private readonly IUnitOfWork _unitOfWork;
    private readonly ILogger _logger;
    private readonly IConfiguration _config;
    private readonly HttpClient _myClient;
    public AdminBranchService(
        ApplicationDbContext dbContext,
        IUnitOfWork unitOfWork,
        ILogger logger,
        IMapper mapper,
        IConfiguration config,
        HttpClient myClient
        )
    {
        _dbContext = dbContext;
        _mapper = mapper;
        _unitOfWork = unitOfWork;
        _logger = logger;
        _config = config;
        _myClient = myClient;
    }
    public async Task<BaseResponse> CreateBranchAsync()
    {
        var branchResponse = new BaseResponse();
        var branches = new List<Branch>();
        try
        {
            string branchUrl = _config.GetSection("Endpoints").GetValue<string>("branchUrl");
            _myClient.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Clear();
            _myClient.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Add(new MediaTypeWithQualityHeaderValue("application/json"));
            HttpResponseMessage response = _myClient.GetAsync(branchUrl).Result;

            var stringResult = response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync().Result;
            BranchResponse list = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<BranchResponse>(stringResult);
            foreach (var singleBranch in list.Branches)
            {
                Branch res = new Branch();
                if (_dbContext.Branches.Any(x => x.BranchName == singleBranch.BranchName))
                {
                    res.BranchNumber = singleBranch.BranchNumber;
                    _unitOfWork.Branches.Update(res);
                }
                else
                {
                    //set all fields here
                    res.BranchName = singleBranch.BranchName;
                    res.BranchNumber = singleBranch.BranchNumber;
                    await _unitOfWork.Branches.InsertAsync(res);
                }
                await _unitOfWork.Save();
            }              
            _logger.Information("Branches Added Successfully");
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            _logger.Error("An Error occured " + ex.ToString());
        }
        return branchResponse;
    }
}
```

ConnectionConfiguration:

```
public static class ConnectionConfiguration
{
    public static void AddDbContextAndConfigurations(this IServiceCollection services, IWebHostEnvironment env, IConfiguration config)
    {
        services.AddDbContextPool<ApplicationDbContext>(options =>
        {
            string connStr;
            connStr = config.GetConnectionString("DefaultConnection");
            options.UseSqlServer(connStr);
        });
    }
}
```

HangFireServiceExtension:

```
public static class HangFireServiceExtension
{
    public static void AddHangFireConfigurations(this IServiceCollection services, IConfiguration config)
    {
        string connStr;
        connStr = config.GetConnectionString("DefaultConnection");
        services.AddHangfire(configuration => configuration
                .SetDataCompatibilityLevel(CompatibilityLevel.Version_170)
                .UseSimpleAssemblyNameTypeSerializer()
                .UseRecommendedSerializerSettings()
                .UseSqlServerStorage(connStr, new SqlServerStorageOptions
                {
                    CommandBatchMaxTimeout = TimeSpan.FromMinutes(5),
                    SlidingInvisibilityTimeout = TimeSpan.FromMinutes(5),
                    QueuePollInterval = TimeSpan.Zero,
                    UseRecommendedIsolationLevel = true,
                    DisableGlobalLocks = true
                }));
        services.AddHangfireServer();
    }
}
```

Program.cs:

```
builder.Services.ConfigureAutoMappers();
// Db Injection
builder.Services.AddDbContextAndConfigurations(environment, configuration);
// HangFire
builder.Services.AddHangFireConfigurations(configuration);

app.UseHangfireDashboard();

RecurringJob.AddOrUpdate<IAdminBranchService>("Post_All_Branches", service => service.CreateBranchAsync(),
            Cron.Daily(2, 0), TimeZoneInfo.Local);
```

What I want to achieve is that by every 2am daily the recurring job should run. It should insert fresh records and update existing ones.

However, on the third day of deployment, no record is found in the database. The HangFire RecurringJob is not running.

Where have I missed it, and how do I correct this?

Thank you

Comment: as i can see you are storing hangfire jobs also in sqlserver database, did you verified if the job is stored properly ? you can also check via Hangfire dashboard if the job is added properly with required cron expression.

Comment: @Nitz - When I went to the HangFire dashboard and triggers it, then it works. Why didn't run on it's own. What is missing in my code?

Comment: is cron expression was represented correctly ? , can you put a screenshot of hangfire dashboard if possible